Manejo de try catch en php
Tengo el siguiente código en el cual estoy probando el funcionamiento del try-catch y tengo mi código asi:
<?php
$var1 = 5;
$var2 = 3;

function suma($valor1, $valor2)
{
    return $valor1 + $valor2;
}

try{
    $result = suma($var1, $var3);
    echo $result;
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Variable no definida";
}
?>

Como pueden ver estoy tratando de atrapar un error que se produce al enviar como parámetro una variable que no esta definida $var3.
Asi como tengo el código no esta sucediendo nada, es decir me lanza el error de variable indefinida y me muestra como resultado el valor de la variable $var1, además de que no esta entrando al bloque catch.
He visto muchos códigos y manejan el try-catch asi como lo estoy haciendo pero también he visto otros ejemplos en donde manejan la línea throw new Exception(); en el bloque try para lanzar la excepción.
Entonces se debe agregar esa línea throw o no es necesario agregarla o porque no me esta funcionando el try-catch??

Según el código que has propuesto PHP no emite excepciones automáticamente para una variable no está definida, emite un notice ... y eso pasa desapercivido por el try catch ...

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

Según el código que has propuesto, el problema se debe a que PHP no lanza automáticamente una excepción cuando encuentra una variable no definida. En su lugar, emite un aviso (notice). Las excepciones en PHP funcionan principalmente para errores más graves que ocurren durante la ejecución del programa y no para avisos o advertencias.
Para que un notice sea escalado a error, se requiere de la implementacion de set_error_handler en conjunto con:
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On

Como ejemplo aqui yo implemente algo bastante elavorado para manejar la situacion que mencionas:
https://github.com/arcanisgk/PHP-Development-Tools/blob/main/src/BugCatcher.php
te puede servir como guia para tu desarrollo.

Siguiendo tu respuesta, veo que PHP lanza una advertencia cuando se tiene una variable no definida y dices que esto no es relevante para las excepciones ya que son para errores graves, bueno cambie la situación y ahora estoy invocando una función que no esta definida, PHP lanza Error Fatal y el try-catch sigue sin hacer su función. No dijiste que las excepciones son para errores graves, ahi esta uno y las excepciones siguen sin funcionar, entonces que es lo que esta pasando??

@JorgeAlonso pero es que eso no funciona asi tan simple, el try catch solo funcionara en tiempo real, el Error fatal se detecta en el parseo del codigo PHP antes de ser ejecutado ...

por ese motivo es que los error handler se declara en el .htaccess o php.ini y no dentro del codigo, ya que si hay un error en el paseo de codigo php se detectara el error y no llegara a la ejecucion ...

cualquier cosa si quieres profundisar en mi perfil encontraras como contactarme por discord

Haber si te entendi, lo que esta pasando es que primero revisa que no haya errores en el código para posteriormente seguir con la ejecución del mismo, y en esa revisión es donde detecta esos errores y como no pone nada en ejecución entonces el try-catch no funciona

exacto ... y por eso dependes del trow ... para que funcione...

perooo si pones en un .htaccess un prepend de un archivo php que controles los 3 niveles de errores ... podras capturar hasta los suspiros de los usuarios XD ...

los try catch de php no funcionan como los de .net o javascript ... por eso imagino que tiene un mal concepto... php es un lenguaje que pasa por al menos 2 proceso: el parseo de codigo y la ruta que se ejecutara... y luego la ejecucion del mismo ...

Como ya se ha dicho, las variables no definidas no lanzan una Excepción, sino un Warning, una advertencia, la cual no rompe el código a un nivel fatal.
No obstante, tú puedes personalizar el código y hacer que levante Excepciones en casos en los que por definición del lenguaje no se levanten.
Dado que para una variable no definida no tiene demasiada utilidad para comprender las excepciones, veamos un caso más útil y basado en un escenario más conforme a la realidad.
Consideremos que desde un formulario debes recibir dos valores para sumar. En la función, vamos a controlar que se hayan recibido en la super global $_GET dos valores bajo una clave valueOne y valueTwo respectivamente. Si se reciben esos valores haremos la suma, en caso contrario lanzaremos una Excepción mediante throw la cual será capturada en el bloque que llama a sumar.
El código de la función suma sería este:
<?php
        
    function suma($data)
    {
        $valueOne=$data['valueOne'] ?? null;
        $valueTwo=$data['valueTwo'] ?? null;
        if(!is_null($valueOne) && !is_null($valueTwo))
        {
            return sprintf("El resultado de la suma es: %d.",$valueOne+$valueTwo);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Alguno de los valores de la suma no está definido.");
        }
    }

?>

Ahora vamos a probarla en dos escenarios, una correcto y otro de error.
Escenario correcto
<?php

    # Se pasan los dos valores, todo OK
    $_GET=['valueOne'=>5, 'valueTwo'=>3];
    
    try
    {
        echo suma($_GET);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
     
?>

Salida:
El resultado de la suma es: 8.


Escenario de Error
<?php

    # No se pasa uno de los dos valores
    $_GET=['valueOne'=>5];
    
    try
    {
        echo suma($_GET);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
        
?>

Salida:
Alguno de los valores de la suma no está definido.

Pero, ya que estamos, vamos a darle más seriedad a nuestra función suma, controlando otros posibles problemas. Por ejemplo, el usuario, en vez de un número, puede escribir una letra. En cuyo caso, tampoco se levanta una Excepción, sino un Warning de que se está intentando sumar un valor no numérico. Podemos controlar eso, metiéndolo todo en una sola Excepción o bien podemos levantar Excepciones personalizadas por cada caso o por grupos de casos, pero ese sería ya otro asunto...
<?php

    # Se pasa una letra en valueOne, Error
    $_GET=['valueOne'=>'a', 'valueTwo'=>3];
    
    try
    {
        echo suma($_GET);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    
    function suma($data)
    {
        $valueOne=$data['valueOne'] ?? null;
        $valueTwo=$data['valueTwo'] ?? null;
        $valueOne=is_numeric($valueOne) ? $valueOne : null;
        $valueTwo=is_numeric($valueTwo) ? $valueTwo : null;
    
        if(!is_null($valueOne) && !is_null($valueTwo))
        {
            return sprintf("El resultado de la suma es: %d.",$valueOne+$valueTwo);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Alguno de los valores de la suma no está definido o es incorrecto.");
        }
    }

?>

Salida:
Alguno de los valores de la suma no está definido o es incorrecto.

El quid de la cuestión es simple, como puedes ver. La Excepción se lanza throw dentro de la función, y se captura dentro del bloque de código que llama a la función.
Veamos un ejemplo donde sí podría levantarse una Excepción. Consideremos un ejemplo de división, donde si intentas dividir por 0 se levanta un DivisionByZeroError. En ese caso, la función en sí misma debe incluir un bloque try ... catch que capture el posible error.
Una función divide se podría escribir así:
function divide($data)
{
    $valueOne=$data['valueOne'] ?? null;
    $valueTwo=$data['valueTwo'] ?? null;
    $valueOne=is_numeric($valueOne) ? $valueOne : null;
    $valueTwo=is_numeric($valueTwo) ? $valueTwo : null;
    if(!is_null($valueOne) && !is_null($valueTwo))
    {
        try 
        {
            return sprintf("El resultado de la división es: %d.",intdiv($valueOne,$valueTwo));
        } 
        catch (DivisionByZeroError $e) 
        {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Alguno de los valores de la suma no está definido o es incorrecto.");
    }
}

Veamos un escenario de DivisionByZeroError:
# Se pasan 0 en el divisor, DivisionByZeroError 
$_GET=['valueOne'=>9, 'valueTwo'=>0];

try
{
    echo divide($_GET);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

Salida:
Division by zero

Los demás escenarios funcionan parecido al código de más arriba.
Si analizas la función anterior, verás que dentro del catch hemos capturado un eventual error de división por 0. Al respecto puedes hacer tres cosas:

Imprimir el mensaje (es lo que hacemos en el ejemplo, por simplicidad),

Relanzar la excepción mediante un throw $e; (sería la práctica recomendada si estuvieras escribiendo un manejador de errores, ver este post para más detalles)

Relanzar cualquier otro tipo de Excepción, sea genérica mediante throw new Exception($e); o personalizada mediante throw new UnaExceptionPersonalizadaCualquiera($e);


